# Criar uma ordem personalizada em SQL

Tags: sql, order-by

Eu tenho uma tabela (`groups`) em SQL com a seguinte estrutura:

```
id | name | description | display_order | ...
```

O campo `display_order` foi definido como `UNIQUE` e deve ser um inteiro. Sua principal função é ser usado para criar uma ordem personalizada na tabela, através do `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM groups ORDER BY display_order;
```

Contudo, preciso de criar uma query para subir ou descer essa ordem, de modo que altere também os registros de cima e de baixo.

Veja uma *imagem representativa* do que preciso fazer:
http://prntscr.com/jjrxh1.

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| id |       name      | description | display_order  (↓) |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1  | Administradores | ...         | 1                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 3  | Outro Grupo     | ...         | 2                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2  | Moderadores     | ...         | 3                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 4  | Grupo X         | ...         | 4                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

Supondo, portanto, que eu precise subir o grupo "Moderadores" para cima, conforme mostra a imagem, **com base no ID 2**, como ficaria a query?

Comment: No caso, eu precisaria de uma query para trocar o `display_order ` `3` com o `display_order ` `2`. O problema é: não sei como fazer essa query.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução possível seria trocar a coluna display_order para decimal com 1 casa.

Assim você pode subir:

```
UPDATE groups SET display_order=display_order - 1.1 WHERE id=X;
```

Assim você pode descer:

```
UPDATE groups SET display_order=display_order + 1.1 WHERE id=X;
```

Em seguida re-ordenar os registros:

```
UPDATE groups G1 SET display_order=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM groups G2 WHERE G1.display_order<G2.display_order)
```

Cuidado com processos concorrentes que podem bagunçar as coisas, não use INNODB pois ele só faz LOCK na ROW que está mexendo, o ideal é usar MyISAM e trabalhar com 2 Stored Procedures, o MyISAM vai fazer LOCK na TABLE enquanto estiver executando a procedure, assim você não precisa se preocupar com processos concorrentes, agora se você estiver num cenário onde esta table tem muitos registros essa solução não vai te atender pois vai gerar lentidão, seguem procedures em MySQL:

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS SP_GROUP_SOBE(IN SP_PARAM_GROUP_ID INT)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE groups SET display_order=display_order - 1.1 WHERE id=SP_PARAM_GROUP_ID;
        UPDATE groups G1 SET display_order=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM groups G2 WHERE G1.display_order<G2.display_order);
    END //
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS SP_GROUP_DESCE(IN SP_PARAM_GROUP_ID INT)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE groups SET display_order=display_order + 1.1 WHERE id=SP_PARAM_GROUP_ID;
        UPDATE groups G1 SET display_order=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM groups G2 WHERE G1.display_order<G2.display_order);
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para o SQL Server, poderia ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
UPDATE groups
SET groups.display_order = X.ORDEM
FROM groups
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS ORDEM, 
    * 
    FROM groups 
) AS X ON
X.id = groups.id
```

Com isso, você atualizaria o registro para a ordem conforme o campo id.

Agora se o seu objetivo é alterar "fisicamente" a ordenação, você pode utilizar índices de agrupamento/ordenação.

Answer (score -1):

Assumindo que não pode alterar a tabela actualizando o valor de `display_order`, ficam aqui algumas alternativas para ordenar uma tabela com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| id |       name      | description | display_order  (↓) |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1  | Administradores | ...         | 1                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 3  | Outro Grupo     | ...         | 2                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2  | Moderadores     | ...         | 3                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 4  | Grupo X         | ...         | 4                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

1. Pode simplesmente ordenar por `id` :)

```
SELECT *
  FROM groups
 ORDER BY ID
```

2. Outra alternativa consiste em forçar a ordem que pretende, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM groups 
 ORDER BY name = 'Administradores' DESC, name = 'Moderadores' DESC, display_order;
```

3. ou ainda, de uma forma mais explícita:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM groups 
 ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN name = 'Administradores' THEN 1
            WHEN name = 'Moderadores' THEN 2
            ELSE display_order
          END;
```

Com esta ordenação, o group Moderadores será listado após o grupo Administradores, seguido de todos os grupos restantes, de acordo com o valor de `display_order`

As duas alternativas têm como resultado:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| id |       name      | description | display_order  (↓) |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1  | Administradores | ...         | 1                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 2  | Moderadores     | ...         | 3                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 3  | Outro Grupo     | ...         | 2                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 4  | Grupo X         | ...         | 4                  |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

Link para o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6622/5)